# what is the correct answer?

Tags: word-choice

Old people sometimes seems (in/out of) touch with the modern world.

should it be in or out of?

my english teacher gave us this question on exam yesterday, and she said the correct answer was out of, I argued with my teacher about that "Either fits" but she said NO! "out of" is correct. So any help please

Thank you.

Please don't put my qustion [on hold] :(

Comment: Please don't simply repost a question. Please **edit the original question** to keep everything relevant in one place. (Unfortunately the standard "duplicate" banner here is completely wrong; asking a new question is exactly the wrong thing to do in this case.)

Comment: You're right, grammatically, either fits the sentence.  Someone can be "in touch with..." or "out of touch with..." so technically your teacher is wrong unless he/she is making a derogatory statement about "old" people, in which case, clearly, "out of touch" would be the answer they're looking for.